# Ordenar ul javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

estoy tratando de ordenar un ul con javascript. Pero me encuentro con el problema de que no me lo ordena y a parte me captura solo dos li mi código actual es el siguiente:

```
function ordenarLista(){

    var vaciar = '';
    var ul = document.getElementById("listaCanciones");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var arrayCanciones = new Array();
    var lista = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

    //lista la transformamos en un array
    for(var i=0; i<lista.length;i++){
        //para añadir elementos a un array push
        arrayCanciones.push(lista[i]);
        //ordenamos el array
        console.log(arrayCanciones.sort());
        //agragamos las canciones a la lista
        li.appendChild(arrayCanciones[i]);
    }

    //pinchamos li en el DOM
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

la primera imagen muestra la entrada de datos de un formulario sencillo.
[image: formulario de entrada]

la segunda el resultado de hacer click en ordenar y el console.log resultante.

[image: resultado]

Desconozco porque solo captura dos li y no ordena.

Agradezco toda ayuda.

Comment: No está de más la imagen para explicar el problema, pero aprovechando que puedes publicar el html, css, javascript dentro de un snippet y ver directamente acá como funciona, sugiero que publiques todo el código utilizando esa característica.

Comment: No tengo que argumentar más nada, y si lo hago de esa manera, la web me devuelve que tengo solo código que argumente más... Siento si no está bien publicada la pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te paso esta solución con comentarios de los pasos seguidos y basada en [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42722827/761181) respuesta de SO.

```js
function ordenarLista(idUl){
    //Obtenemos el elemento ul
    let ul = document.getElementById(idUl);    
    //Obtenemos la lista de li
    let lista = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    //Creamos el array a partir de los elementos li
    //A continuación ordenamos con sort (hay que ordenar mirando el textContent y evitando la etiqueta li
    //Por último recorremos el array ya ordenado y vamos haciendo el append en el elemento ul (sobrescribiéndolo)
    let arrayCanciones = Array.from(lista);
    arrayCanciones.sort((a, b) => a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent))
    .forEach(li => ul.appendChild(li));
   
}

ordenarLista("listaCanciones");
```

```html
<ul id="listaCanciones">
<li>zzz</li>
<li>aaa</li>
<li>bbb</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: mil gracias @Kiko_L

Answer (score 0):

Aunque ya tienes una respuesta, deseo complementarla con la siguiente solución.

No sé exactamente cómo estás agregando y removiendo elementos a tu elemento `ul`, asi que he implementado mis propios métodos.

En el método `sortSongs`, simplemente uso una función que realiza la comprobación sobre el `Array` de `childNodes`. En dicha comparación ordeno de forma ascendente.

Por otra parte cada vez que se añade un elemento a `ul`, le asigno un atributo `id` de forma dinámica usando `Date.now`, así puedo escoger el elemento que voy a remover.

```js
const addSong = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const song = document.getElementById('song').value;
  if(!song || song == '') return;
  let newSong = document.createElement('li');
  newSong.setAttribute('id', Date.now().toString());
  newSong.innerText = song;
    songs.appendChild(newSong);
}

const removeSong = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  if(songs.hasChildNodes()) {
    const song = document.getElementById('song').value;
    if(!song || song == '') return;
    let id;
    songs.childNodes.forEach((node) => {
      if(node.innerText == song) {
        id = node.getAttribute('id');
      }
    });
    if(!id) return;
    removedSong = document.getElementById(id);
    songs.removeChild(removedSong);
  }
}

const sortSongs = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  if(songs.hasChildNodes()) {
    let sorted = [];
    songs.childNodes.forEach((child) => {
      sorted.push(child);
      sorted.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.innerText == b.innerText ? 0 : (a.innerText < b.innerText ? -1 : 1);
      });
    });
    for(let i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
      songs.appendChild(sorted[i]);
    }
  }
}

let songs = document.getElementById('songs');
let addButton = document.getElementById('add');
let sortButton = document.getElementById('sort');
let removeButton = document.getElementById('remove');
addButton.addEventListener('click', addSong);
sortButton.addEventListener('click', sortSongs);
removeButton.addEventListener('click', removeSong);
```

```css
input, button {
  margin-right: 0.2rem;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="song"></input>
  <button type="button" id="add">Añadir</button>
  <button type="button" id="sort">Ordenar</button>
  <button type="button" id="remove">Eliminar</button>
  <br>
  <ul id="songs"></ul>
</div>
```